# After importing model from a different file I cannot change it

Tags: mesh, materials

I created a model in an alternate file and I am unable to edit anything (modes and materials) if I change modes it says:
[image]

This applies for any mode. I went to edit> lock object modes OFF and that didn't help. Further more the materials are locked.

[image]

How can I go about fixing this

Comment: So you *linked* the model from the different .blend file, not *imported* it, based on the answer you propose. Importing and linking are different contexts in Blender, importing is from formats non-native to Blender like obj, fbx etc. Linking is related to .blend files only

Comment: O I thought importing was what the word importing meant didn't know in blender importing differs

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I found that you can select the object hit the object button in the top left corner>Relations>Make Local>All this separates the link and works!